# Brunch and VueJs with Promise polyfill

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, brunch, babel-polyfill

My code doesn't work in IE and I am having trouble getting to the bottom of it. I need a Promise polyfill, so my goal was to import "babel-polyfill" at my main app.js and see if this worked.

I am running into trouble however, because it seems with VueJs and vue-brunch, somehow the babel code is not being executed in the .vue templates.

I can uses Object.assign in my main app.js file without issue but it does not work in a .vue file. If I remove the line everything otherwise compiles fine.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary fix: include `vue` to `babel-brunch` extensions:

```
babel: {
    pattern: /\.(js|vue)$/
}
```

Also, please make sure `babel-brunch` is after `vue-brunch` in `package.json`.

In future, this won't be necessary because of compiler chaining we are shipping.